# How can I generate text image same as the JLabel label?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I would like to generate text image same as the JLabel label without displaying JLabel.

I tried same Font, same drawing method.
But generated image is not same as JLabel.

My sourcecode is below.
* 'super.paintComponent(g)' has been commented out for clarity that it is the same way. Output image is same.
* Below drawing by 'View.paint' method, but I'm tried 'SwingUtilities2.drawString' too. Two results are the same.

```
    /* Label */
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text) {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //super.paintComponent(g);
            View v = BasicHTML.createHTMLView(this, getText());
            v.paint(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getFontMetrics(
                            getFont()).getAscent()));
        }
    };
    label.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 13));

    /* Image */
    FontMetrics fm = label.getFontMetrics(font);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(fm.stringWidth(text),
                fm.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    g2d.setFont(label.getFont());

    // Clear background.
    g2d.setPaint(label.getBackground());
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    // Draw string.
    g2d.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    View v = BasicHTML.createHTMLView(label, text);
    v.paint(g2d, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(), 
            g2d.getFontMetrics().getAscent()));

    // ... output image to file ...
```

Result image is following.
[JLabel]
[image]
[Generated image]
[image]

Generated image is slightly thin-faced, as compared to JLabel's capture.
How can I generate text image same as the JLabel label?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is View necessary here? Wouldn't it be possible to render the label directly on Graphics2D by calling label.paint(g2b) ?

Comment: It is very easily way but the results was the same. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you might need to create a compatible buffered image (compatible to the display)

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();

// Create an image that does not support transparency
BufferedImage bimage = gc.createCompatibleImage(100, 100, Transparency.OPAQUE);
```

This will at least get you on a close with the graphics been used to render to the screen

You might also like to pay around with the [rendering quality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html) as well

Kleopatra did a post on a similar question awhile ago, you might to try and hunt it down

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will search similar question & try any idea.

Comment: I solved my problem by RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB. Thanks!

Comment: I would test it on a few systems to see if the it looks any different on different monitors. But ace otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

- Why do you use `BasicHTML.createView` if you want to have the same as `JLabel`?
- You could use the `JLabel` directly (if you only want the text and not the background, set `opaque` to `false` and the `border` to `null`)
- or you can use [`g2d.drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: I'm creating software, that is search for text location from web browser capture image.
I thought trying search on capture image by generated same text image.
JLabel has displaying text same as browser text. Therefore I'm not using the 'g2d.drawString'.  I would like to generate JLabel's text image.